# How To Access Invocation Count in Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, profiling, project, cpu-usage

I have a project I'm working on and I need to do some profiling now that the bulk of the coding is finished. However one of the stipulations for completion is that I need to find out Total Time taken for the methods to execute and also how many times a particular method is executed. However it's driving me nuts trying to find Invocation Count on Netbeans. One of the help pages online said click the Drop Down Arrow in the window but all I can see as a selection column called "Hits"; I googled that and no explanations crop up. Anyone here have experience with NetBeans profiling? Thanks in advance.

[image: My Screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the solution may be as simple as changing the list selection labeled **Profile** in the OP screen shot from **All classes** to **Selected methods**. However, if that is not the case, here is a walk through of the setup to get the invocation count for selected methods in a results snapshot when profiling in NetBeans:

- Select **Profile** -> **Profile Project** for your project.
- If no profiling has been set up the screen should look similar to this:

[image: nb1]

- Click the **Configure Session** button (or link) shown in the screen shot above.
- From the drop down list check **User Defined Profiling Points**, and select **Methods**.

[image: nb2]

- This will cause a **Settings** cog wheel icon on the far right to be displayed. Click that to display another drop list labeled **Profile** with a default selection of **All classes**.
- Click that **Profile** drop list, and select **Selected methods** which will allow **Invocations** to be shown in the profiling results. (The screen shot in the OP shows **All Classes** is selected instead.)

[image: nb25]

- Having chosen the profile **Selected methods**, click the **Add** button shown in the screen shot below, and select the methods to profile in the **Select Method** dialog:

[image: nb3]

- Finally run your app with the selected profiling options by clicking the **Profile** button with the green triangle to its left.
- The **Invocations** column (n.b. not ***Invocation Count***) should be displayed in the results. If not then click the black inverted triangle on the far right of the column headers row, which allows toggling the display of each column in the results snapshot.

[image]

These instruction specifically apply to the most recent stable release of NetBeans (8.2) but the general principles should be valid for earlier releases as well, though possibly with some differences in the details.

Comment: That was absolutely spot on. Thank you so much!